# How to automatically wake up virtualenv and gunicorn at nginx?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have a digital ocean server with a project that works correctly, but everytime I `reboot` the server, or I close the `ssh session` to this the `gunicorn service` is stopped adn then I am not able to connect.

The server has ubuntu 18 and `NGINX` as a web server.

My `gunicorn` statements is:

```
gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock computationalMarketing.wsgi:application
```

Also I need before execute this statement, enable the `virtual environtment`.

Is there a way to start the `virtualenv` & `gunicorn` every time and do not worry about it?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I am creating the systemd Service File (attached script below), but it shows the following error:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of gunicorn.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-03 11:57:19 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 8446 ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 8446 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: Starting gunicorn daemon...
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[8446]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[8446]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate: No such process
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
root@tfm-rius:/var/www/computationalMarketing/computationalMarketing/code/computationalMarketing#
```

**Script**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/computationalMarketing
ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/computationalMarketing/code/computationalMarketing/gunicorn --access-logfile --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock computationalMarketing.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Question**

This error is related with the User used at service body, or maybe with one of the execStart command?

*Edit purpose*: Show my next step to solve the question.

Comment: this might be off the topic, but if you plan on getting to the Centos7 hese is the script to spawn nginx+gunicorn+mongo, no virtual env tho https://gist.github.com/76creates/f97d5ec1f29c8796de0e85e5f923ff50 , with systemD service it will make sure its up on each reboot

Comment: You should be using a systemd service to start gunicorn. DigitalOcean have [lots of docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file) on doing this with gunicorn.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman for the docs, I am following and applying them.

But I will edit the question because I have some doubts

Comment: I don't think your user should be 'root', it should be the nginx user which is often also www-data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I change the user for www-data and now the error is: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied

Should I give 777 permissions to this user to the path: "/var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate"

Comment: @DanielRoseman If i do: su www-data the response is: This account is currently not available. Can this be related with the privileges specified above?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to start virtualenv explicitly. You can install gunicorn inside your virtualenv and run it like `/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --pythonpath=/path/to/your/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages <other args>`, and it will be run by virtualenv python

Comment: Don't recommend rc.local for recent systems, OP should be using systemd.

Comment: Thanks @EugenePrimako I attached new data to understant better what I have done later.